# sed: how to replace a specific string

Tags: sed

I have an issue I am trying to solve with sed. My goal is to quote a the content after content= if the content is not already quoted.

Here is the concrete example:

```
<meta name="ProgId" content=Word.Document>
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15">
```

I would like to add quotes around Word.Document so at the end have:

```
<meta name="ProgId" content="Word.Document">
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15">
```

I was trying with

```
sed -i 's@content="\(.*\)"@content="\1"/@g' "$1"
```

However this is not working.

Thank you.

Comment: `content="` There is no `"`, so why match it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `"` in the input behind `content=`, so you shouldn't match it. You could match up until a space or `>`.

```
sed 's@content=\([^"][^ >]*\)@content="\1"@'
```

Note that you should use XML aware tools to parse XML documents.

Comment: Thanks! This works partly. In the case the words after the content= are quoted, the sed will add another pair of quotes and this is not the goal. Sorry I didn't mention this in my question. I will rephrase.

Comment: Well, then match not a quote. Fixed.

Comment: @Miloš you should be able to modify the suggested answer for that case.. `sed 's@content=\([^" >]*\)>@content="\1">@'` is one way to do it.. btw, there is an extra `/` left over before last `@`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
sed -E 's/content=([^">]+)/content="\1"/'
```

Explanation:

In this way, you tell sed to substitute everything is after `content=` and before `>` only if it doesn't start with `"`. I used regex grouping to replace the content with itself surrounded by `"`.

Input:

```
<meta name="ProgId" content=Word.Document>
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15">
```

Output:

```
<meta name="ProgId" content="Word.Document">
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15">
```